# Proof the following statement false – Every real number, a , can be written as $a=\frac{p}{q}$, where p and q are integers.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I really Faced Difficulties finding a counter example I really needed hints here.

Comment: The question is- Every real number,a, can be written as a=p/q, where p and q are integers.

Comment: $\sqrt2$ is a counterexample. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proof_by_infinite_descent).

Comment: You faced difficulties finding a counter example or proving one? Surely you know about rational versus irrational numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rational number $x\in\Bbb Q$ can be written in the form $x=\frac{m}{n}$ for suitable $n,m\in\Bbb Z$ where $n\ne 0$. Irrational numbers cannot be written in that form. The set of real numbers ($\Bbb R$) is the union of rational and irrational numbers. So to say every $a\in\Bbb R$ can be written in the form $a=\frac{p}{q}$ for $q,p\in\Bbb Z$ and $q\ne 0$ is certainly false, because irrational numbers cannot be written in that form, yet the set of irrational numbers is contained in the set of real numbers. So to prove the given statement false, just choose any irrational number (e.g. $\pi ,\sqrt 2$, etc.) as your $a$ value, and the statement does not hold true.